# Facebook chat using Google App Engine(Java) problem

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp, facebook-chat

Is it possible to send/receive chat messages to Facebook chat using Google App Engine(Java)? I was trying to implement this functionality for a whole week. I read the [XMPP](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html) Doc in GAE, but I still can't implement Facebook chat in my application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check already existing implementations. Typing "facebook chat java" in google led me to [this](http://code.google.com/p/facebookchat-java/downloads/detail?name=facebookchat-src-20080824.tar.gz), which can be a help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this is only for desktop apps, I think it wont work on GAE :(.

Comment: Note that "facebookchat-java" is a deprecated project since Facebook now uses open XMPP standards for integration with IM clients.